# Spectral density of square of AWGN

Tags: stochastic-processes, cross-correlation, spectral-analysis, white-noise

Additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN), $w(t)$, is usually modeled with the following assumptions

- For a given $t_0$, $w(t_0)$ follows a normal distribution and
- $R_{ww} = \sigma^2 \delta(t)$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the normal distribution and $\delta(t)$ is a Dirac delta distribution. Its spectral density is therefore flat.

What can be said about the spectral density of the square of such a process, beyond the fact that $w^2(t_0)$ will follow a chi-square distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocorrelation function of a *continuous-time* white Gaussian noise process is generally taken to be a some constant $K$ times $\delta(t)$ and $K$ is **NOT** the standard deviation of the Gaussian random variable $w(t_0)$, nor the variance, for that matter. In particular, $w(t)$ cannot be treated as a Gaussian random variable with *finite* variance and the concept of $(w(t_0))^2$ as a chi-square random variable is mostly meaningless.  See my answer to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8629/235) on dsp.SE for some details.

For a *discrete-time* random process, the random variables $w(nT), n \in \mathbb Z$ are a time series of independent zero-mean Gaussian random variables with fixed *variance* $\sigma^2$ and so the $(w(nT))^2$ are indeed a time series of independent 
scalar multiples of a chi-square random variable with one degree of freedom.